# How do I make this animation play, then stop, then play again after a set amount of time? (css)

Tags: html, css

I'm making a text animation for my friend's website and I'm trying to make a flicker effect, it works, however, it plays once, and I want it to play, then stop, then start again. THe make I've tried only messes it up. Does anyone know a solution?

(my animation code)

```css
.neon span {
  animation: flicker 900ms linear 2;
  }
.neon .delay1 {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
  }
.neon .delay2 {
  animation-delay: 2.0s;
  }
@keyframes flicker
  {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
   10% { opacity: 1; }
   20% { opacity: 0; }
   40% { opacity: 1; }
   50% { opacity: 0; }
   60% { opacity: 1; }
   80% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
  }
```

In the `animation: flicker 900ms linear 2;` line of code I've tried putting `infinte` but when I do that it flickers supers fast with no break. I want it to flicker kinda slow then stop, then flicker again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animation-delay` only specifies the delay time before the animation **first starts**.

`animation-iteration-count` which (for example) you might specify in your `animation` shorthand as `infinite` doesn't include that in between interations.

So, you have to 'fake' it by manually building that into your `@keyframes`.

```css
.neon span {
  animation: flicker 900ms linear 1.4s infinite;
 }

@keyframes flicker {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  10% { opacity: 1; }
  20% { opacity: 0; }
  40% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  60% { opacity: 1; } /* 'fake' delay */
  80% { opacity: 1; } /* 'fake' delay */
  100% { opacity: 1; } /* 'fake' delay */
}
```

In the example above, it will wait 1.4 seconds upon initial page load, then start to flicker between `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` for 60% of your `900ms` duration, then stay `opacity: 1` for the other 40%.

How fast it flickers will depend on your `animation-duration` (e.g. 900ms) divided by the number of selectors (steps) over the course of your `@keyframes`.
So, if you increase/decrease the duration, or decrease/increase the number of keyframe selectors (e.g. 0%, 1%, 2%, 3% ... 100%) it will flicker slower/faster.

Then it will restart immediately after and repeat infinitely.

Discussed here:

[CSS animation delay in repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887889/css-animation-delay-in-repeating)

[CSS animation delay between iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287175/css-animation-delay-between-iterations)

Comment: This works perfectly the only problem is it doesn't look great, is there a way you think for it to flicker a random number of times, then delay, and then repeat? When I do this method is just flickers the same amount of times indefinitely and it doesn't look great. If you could help me with this that'd be great.

Comment: Play around with the `animation-timing-function` which your example currently sets to `linear`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: The `steps()`, `jump-start`, `jump-end` values might be able to achieve what you need. I've never used it that way before, but play around with it.